# Why do cells in the cerebral cortex act as interacting nonlinear oscillators?

Tags: cell-biology, brain

I'm not a biologist, but I'd like to know something about EEG analysis. 
In particular, I have read that EEG signal derive from cells in the cerebral cortex and hippocampus. And that these cells act as many interacting nonlinear oscillators.

I'd like to understand why they are oscillators and why their behaviour is nonlinear. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: [This link](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/26/23/6213) could probably give you your answer. Sorry that i'm too tired to read and vulgarise it at this time :)